# How to recover file that is accidently removed in linux

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I have accidentally removed my apache2 startup file `/etc/init.d/apache2` using `rm /etc/init.d/apache2` command.

How can I get that back?

Comment: By restoring from your backup.

Comment: Writing it from scratch will probably be the easiest approach. ( Trying to get it back from ext* is a nightmare, if not impossible )

Comment: `ed` can be used (if you have a really good memory).

Comment: **Remount read-only. Right now.** `mount -oremount,ro /`. Then continue looking for recovery programs, probably on a different machine because a read-only root is not appreciated by many programs.

Comment: It's crazy how the Linux terminal doesn't have a garbage bin.

Comment: Name one other OS that has "a garbage bin" that the command line utilities use.

Comment: This is Unix. You're supposed to be a grown-up.  And have backups, just in case.

Comment: @Hermann: if you are in a FreeDesktop (Gnome, KDE, XFCE) environment `trash /etc/init.d/apache2` works as does `restore-trash`. I've never used them as source control and backups have always been sufficient and protect against more than a bad `rm`. http://www.ramendik.ru/docs/trashspec.html

Answer (score 3):

In this case the file is part of a package in the distribution. Just reinstall it.

In apt-based systems like [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=etc%2Finit.d%2Fapache2&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) or [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=apache2&mode=exactfilename&suite=karmic&arch=any), i believe it's just `sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2.2-common`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your package manager, you can just reinstall the apache package.  It will add that file back.  Make sure you back up your configurations before you try though.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help you after the event, but I highly recommend [etckeeper](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/). It maintains your `/etc` in a git/mercurial/darcs/bzr repository more or less automatically. It works best on Debian/Ubuntu where it's tied in with apt to make automatic commits before and after package installs, but it's usable on any Unix system. I'm using it on Mac OS X, for example. I can see the entire history of my `/etc` directory, and pull out previous versions of files when I need to.

Answer (score 0):

http://e2undel.sourceforge.net/recovery-howto.html

Never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your filesystem you could try the following:

- http://www.xs4all.nl/~carlo17/howto/undelete_ext3.html
- http://www.ehow.com/how_2064953_recover-deleted-files-linux.html